# Test a RichCoFlatMapFunction in Apache Flink

Tags: testing, apache-flink, flink-streaming

i'm trying to test a RichCoFlatMapFunction that i'm using to make a left join of two streams it is something like this:

```java
    private ValueState<Card> currentValueState;
    private ListState<Card> historicListState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        currentValueState = getRuntimeContext().getState(new ValueStateDescriptor<>("Current State", Card.class));
        historicListState = getRuntimeContext().getListState(new ListStateDescriptor<>("historic state", Card.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap1(Card currentCard, Collector<Tuple2<Card, List<Card>>> out) throws Exception {
        Iterable<Card> historicCardList =  historicListState.get();
        if (Iterables.size(historicCardList) > 0) {
            out.collect(new Tuple2<>(currentCard, Lists.newArrayList(historicCardList) ));
        } else {
            currentValueState.update(currentCard);
            out.collect(new Tuple2<>(currentCard, null));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flatMap2(Card historicCard, Collector<Tuple2<Card, List<Card>>> out) throws Exception {
        historicListState.add(historicCard);
    }
```

In the Method flatMap1 i'm returning a null when a historic Card is not found

```
out.collect(new Tuple2<>(currentCard, null));
```

The problem is that when i'm trying to test this whole functionality i'm receiving this error:

> Automatic type extraction is not possible on candidates with null values. Please specify the types directly.

This is how i'm trying to test the richCoFlatMapFunction

```java
    @Test
    public void testFlatMap() throws Exception {
        final Card current = currentCard(2L);
        final Card historic = historicCard(2L);
        final List<Card> historicList = new ArrayList<>();
        historicList.add(historic);
        CoStreamFlatMap<Card, Card, Tuple2<Card, List<Card>>> operator = new CoStreamFlatMap<>(new LeftJoin());
        KeyedTwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<Long, Card, Card, Tuple2<Card, List<Card>>> testHarness =
                new KeyedTwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<>(
                        operator,
                        (Card c) -> c.getCardHash(),
                        (Card h) -> h.getCardHash(),
                        BasicTypeInfo.LONG_TYPE_INFO);
        testHarness.setup();
        testHarness.open();
        testHarness.processElement1(new StreamRecord<>(current));
        testHarness.processElement2(new StreamRecord<>(historic));
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Object> expectedOutput = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        expectedOutput.add(new StreamRecord<>(new Tuple2<>(current, historicList)));
        // Check that the result is correct
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Object> actualOutput = testHarness.getOutput();
        TestHarnessUtil.assertOutputEquals("Output was not correct.", expectedOutput, actualOutput);
    }
```

Any help would me much appreciated, i'm kinda new on Apache Flink and Unit Testing with it
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `KeyedTwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness` does not know how to serialize the outputs of your `LeftJoin` operator. You can specify an output serializer via the `KeyedTwoInputStreamOperatorTestHarness.setup(TypeSerializer<OUT> outputSerializer)`.

In your case it would be:

```
testHarness.setup(TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<Card, List<Card>>>() {}).createSerializer(new ExecutionConfig()));
```